# check if data exist in a table if yes do this else this(data do exist) but only else part is working

Tags: sql-server

I've got a table with uid, username and password
and the procedure to check for login

```
create procedure getlogin(@username varchar(50),@password varchar(20),@granted int output)
as 
begin 
    if exists (select top 1 uid 
               from user_detail 
               where username = @username and password = @password)
       set @granted=1
    else
       set @granted=-1
end
```

but am always getting -1

Comment: How are you **calling** this stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variables, setting them, and running the query to see if you are getting results?  My guess is you are not.  Probably because your username or password doesn't match the table, possibly because of spaces or because of case sensitivity.  If that query works then try the whole contents of the SP without the SP itself .. then last but not least double check that you are using the OUTPUT clause when calling the SP.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine to me.
Here's an example on how you should call and test your code:

```
create table user_detail
(   uid int primary key,
    username varchar(50),
    password varchar(20)
    )
go
insert user_detail values(1,'a','b')
go
create procedure getlogin(@username varchar(50),@password varchar(20),@granted int output)
as 
begin 
    if exists (select top 1 uid 
               from user_detail 
               where username = @username and password = @password)
       set @granted=1
    else
       set @granted=-1
end
go
declare @granted int
exec getlogin 'a','a', @granted output
select @granted
exec getlogin 'a','b', @granted output
select @granted
```

BTW You may want to encrypt your password using the HASHBYTES function. You can read more about it in Books Online.